# NotifyCollectionChangedAction: object instance on removal?

Tags: c#, collections, inotifycollectionchanged

I am currently implementing the INotifyCollectionChanged interface for a collection with generally quite critical and short-lived items. All of those items implement IDispose, which can be called immediatly **before** the removal from the collection. I do not have any control about the destruction order, I will just have to take it as it comes.

My trouble is now, how to propagate the "Remove" actions. The NotifyCollectionChangedAction constructor does provide a variant with only the action specified, but I do have an index of the removed item. Sadly there is no overload taking only an index.

So I guess I could:

- Only pass the "Remove" action
- Pass the remove action along with a "null" object and an index
- Pass the remove action along with a disposed object and an index

Which of those would you prefer? I am a little afraid of implementing such a "core" interface wrong and possibly cause not obviously related bugs ...

I couldn't find any guidelines what happens with the items that are in the "change" lists, are there any available?

Sidenote: The collection will not be immediatly bound to WPF, if thats important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in MSDN, the only appropriate sets of data for *remove* are the [overload taking the instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653207.aspx), and the [overload taking instance and index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653212.aspx). You could *try* the latter passing just the index; it *might* work... but given the existence of the first overload, I'm not hopeful. If you *don't* give it the object, downstream code *may* have no way of knowing which item changed. So I think you're going to have to pass the object. This shouldn't generally cause issues, as most code is simply going to use it for reference check; the object is still *there* (it hasn't been collected) - it has just been disposed, where "just" is used... subjectively (as this *could* still cause issues).

Another option, of course, is to wrap the object in a facade. Then it doesn't matter if the actual object is disposed, set to null and/or garbage-collected; the facade is still there (but it should be coded to handle the object being unavailable).

As a final option; do you have to use their collection? Could you not just *wrap* that collection, so that *you* choose when to tell it about these things? THen you retain complete control over lifetimes...

Comment: Whoops, facading the object in the collection is something I haven't thought of ... Thanks, I will check back with my co-workers.

Comment: Wrapping the collection itself is another good idea, guess I need to think more out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are borked.

- Destruction of objects before the removal is a violation of how the interface should work. Point. You can not control it - then you can not implemtn NotifyCollectionChangedAction properly.
- You have to pass the index and the removed object.